# Unknown Format in feature testing rails capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist, ruby-on-rails-5.1

[image]

I am writing capybara tests. There is a link I have in the view. When I click over the link that links open a pop-up js warning. I have configured Js. in capybara by using phantomjs and petergiest gem.

[image]

Comment: Show your test code and Capybara config so there’s at least enough info to attempt to diagnose - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have add all information gemfile spec file and configuration fil

Comment: Add as code blocks in your question - not untitled pictures

Answer (score 0):

Without the requested information it's impossible to give an exact answer, but the error you are seeing means the app is requesting a non-JS response (probably HTML).  This could be occurring for a couple of reasons

1. You're not actually running the test with a JS supporting driver.  I don't see any `js` metadata on your scenarios so depending on how you've configured Capybara/RSpec this could by your issue. To confirm, swap from Poltergeist to using Selenium with Chrome or Firefox (non-headless while trying to debug) so you can see if the browser actually starts
2. You have a JS error preventing JS from running so a normal request is being made instead of XHR. This could be because you actually have a bug in your JS or because you're using Poltergeist/PhantomJS which is massively out of date in JS/CSS support. To test this, swap to using Selenium with Chrome or Firefox and look in the developer console.
3. Your link isn't correctly configured to make an ajax request - This is impossible to tell without the HTML of the link

Additionally, neither of the tests shown in your image are actually asserting/expecting anything so it's very unclear what exactly you're trying to test.